# Getting an error message saying the variable has not been declared when it has

Tags: c, struct, declaration

Here is my code:

```
struct data {
   char carReg[6]; 
   char make[20], model[20], colour[20];
   int numPrevOwners; 
   bool reserved; 
   float reserveAmount; 
};

struct node {
struct data *element;
struct node *next;
};
```

And in my main method I have this:

```
struct node *current, *aNode;
struct data *anElement, *newCar;
FILE *file;

file = fopen("d:car.dat", "r"); //open the file for reading 
if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Nothing found in this file.\n\n");
    printf("\n");
}//end if
else {
    //If it does exist, cars in file should be copied into the linked list
    while(fread(&newCar, sizeof(struct data), 1, file)>0) {         

        aNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        anElement = (struct data *)malloc(sizeof(struct data));

        strcpy(anElement->carReg ,newCar->carReg);
        strcpy(anElement->make, newCar->make);
        strcpy(anElement->model, newCar->model);
        strcpy(anElement->colour, newCar->colour);
        anElement->numPrevOwners = newCar->numPrevOwners;
        anElement->reserved = newCar->reserved;
        anElement->reserveAmount = newCar->reserveAmount;

         if (aNode == NULL)
           printf("Error - no space for the new node\n");

            else { // add data part to the node
                 aNode->element = anElement;
                 aNode->next = NULL;

                 if (isEmpty()) 
                 {
                  front = aNode;
                  last = aNode;
                  }

                  else {
                  last->next = aNode;
                  last = aNode;
                  }

               }
    }//end while

    printf("Cars in the system");
}//end else
```

The error message I'm getting is 'carReg' has not been declared, 'make' has not been declared etc.

Could anyone help with it?

EDIT - I have it updated, it all compiles but the program doesn't run. It runs but says title.exe has stopped running.

Comment: You need `->` instead of `.` with all pointers, not only some of them

Comment: `newCar` shouldn't be a pointer. And currently your code is not saving any of the pointers held in `aNode` or `anElement`.

Comment: @ooga I have edited my comment above. It compiles but doesn't run properly.

Comment: One question per question. That is the rule on Stackoverflow. Instead of editing your question, you should have asked a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `struct data *anElement, *newCar;` with `struct data *anElement; struct data newCar;`.

Currently `fread()` reads `sizeof(struct data)` bytes into a pointer (`&newCar` is an address of a pointer) and this is probably not what you want (and also this is a classical buffer overflow).

This will also fix the errors you're getting because you're trying to access struct members via a pointer using a `.` operator. Changing `newCar` definition will fix that.

Comment: jf95, if the answer solved your problem you should accept it as the solution.